# What is the best approach for Mapping Broker and Web-Applications

Tags: broker, deployer

What is better approach; Need to know what are the pros and cons for both options.

1) Create separate Broker for each web-application. So on publishing each application content will publish to its own Broker. This will increase the number of deployer instances on CD server; but content retrieval will be fast; better performance.

2) Create only one Broker and one Deployer intance that will serve content for all web-applications which are based on Tridion Content. When the content scale up it might be expensive on performance end.

Any comments on same is most welcome; thanks

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I much rather prefer option 2 for:

- Management simplicity
- Flexibility in growth

Given how CD environments can grow (yes, including database here) nowadays, you'd really be needing to have an immense amount of traffic to hit limits here. Some of the sites running Tridion have insane amounts of traffic, and can still handle it on a single broker (clustered servers, of course). And if that's not working for you, then you should probably review your caching strategies.